# Foreign key to get column from another model - Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have been trying to add a new column to my TrainingSubject model called "email" and link its value to another model (Training) via foreign key, and then display it all on front end (back is django, front is react.

I've added this line to **TrainingSubject** model:

```
email = models.CharField(_('Email assigned'), max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
```

and this one to **Training** model:

```
email_to = models.ForeignKey(TrainingSubject, related_name='manager_email', default='', blank=True)
```

so it all reads as follows:

```
    class TrainingSubject(models.Model):
    """TrainingSubject model for storing subjects."""

    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=160, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(_('Email assigned'), max_length=100, default='', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Training subject')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Training subjects')


class Training(models.Model):
    """Training model for storing trainings."""

    subject = models.ForeignKey(TrainingSubject, verbose_name=_('subject'),
                                related_name='trainings')
    email_to = models.ForeignKey(TrainingSubject, related_name='manager_email', default='', blank=True)                                
    date = models.DateTimeField(_('date'))
    timezone = models.CharField(
```

The migration cannot be applied, I get this error every single time I start creating these things.

```
        Running migrations:
      Rendering model states... DONE
      Applying sonel_core.0089_training_email_to...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/vagrant/.pyenv/versions/cms/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    psycopg2.IntegrityError: column "email_to_id" contains null values
```

Previously I tried to add it all in one step only, now I have broken it down to two steps: 1. add **email** to TrainingSubject (which work perfectly well) and 2. add **email_to** to Training model and the be able to finally display this email on the front-end.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the field to accept null values, as the table already does have some data, when adding new FK field, null has to be given or a valid values.

```
email_to = models.ForeignKey(TrainingSubject, related_name='manager_email', default='', blank=True, null=True)
```